# What's the reasoning behind the availability of edit history for a message in chat but not in posts (for regular user)?

Tags: support, comments, edits, chat

In chat we (as a regular user) can see a complete history of edits to a message, even made a few seconds apart.

But for a regular user (non-mod/staff) there is no history of edits to a comment in posts (answers or questions) although it is editable for a *longer period* (5 minutes instead of [2 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100682/625056)).

What was the reason behind this?

Comment: Note: Edit history exists for comments as well, but it's only visible to moderators/staff.

Comment: @V2Blast Thank you.  I forgot about it.  Updated the question accordingly.